# How to get value using DOM HTML

Tags: php

I have a html:

```
$content = "
<tr>
   <td class="ttl"><a href="#">Colors</a></td>
   <td class="nfo">Dark Grey, Rose Red, Blue, Brown, Sand White</td>
</tr>";
```

And code php:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);      
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$attbs = $xpath->query("//td[@class='ttl']");
foreach($attbs as $a) { 
    print $a->nodeValue;
}

$values = $xpath->query("//td[@class='nfo']");
foreach($values as $v) { 
    print $v->nodeValue;
}
```

How get value of 2 td but only using 1 foreach

Comment: em... by removing first foreach? Just can't see what's your problem here.

Comment: Just a note, `$content` should use single quotes since double quotes already used for the tag attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Put both classes into a logical OR expression with the `|` operator:

```
$attbs = $xpath->query("//td[@class='ttl'] | //td[@class='nfo']");
foreach($attbs as $a) { 
    print $a->nodeValue;
}
```

This prints:

```
ColorsDark Grey, Rose Red, Blue, Brown, Sand White
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QRlKc1)

Comment: I have been trying to parse some html in php using regex for hoooouuuurrrs, and it was all failing. Thank you so much for this solution that actually worked! Xpath ftw.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$trs = $xpath->query("//tr");
foreach ($trs as $tr) {
    $attbs = $xpath->query("//td[@class='ttl']", $tr);
    $values = $xpath->query("//td[@class='nfo']", $tr);
    echo $attbs->item(0)->nodeValue . '-' .  $values->item(0)->nodeValue . '<br />';
}
```